# error sending email in .NET

Tags: .net, email, smtp

i am getting an error saying "5.7.1: Unable to relay for xxx@gmail.com"

any ideas what this means?

Comment: Please use "c#" tag. 31000+ for this and zero for csharp.

Comment: Another small point: you're not sending email in C#. You're sending email in .NET, using a program you wrote in the C# programming language. Presumably the exact same problem would have occurred if you'd written the code in VB.NET.

Comment: I changed it to "email .net smtp", since it had nothing to do with C# in specific, but plenty to do with both email in general and SMTP in specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the SMTP server you are using doesn't allow relaying - this could be because you're not authenticating, or not sending to an email address that is local.  There is an option (in IIS SMTP anyway) to allow relaying without authentication

Answer (score 2):

The SMTP server has to be configured to relay mail to other domains.

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify a SMTP server? Can we see some of your code?